# How to make JavaScript run after an ajax request updates HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

My code involves fetching some data using jQuery's Ajax. I then append  the result I get from the server to html (in form of buttons). All buttons have a class name mybutton. A separate JavaScript file handles the button click events. Everything works okay for the first Ajax call but I then get an error on second Ajax call. The Ajax calls are made at an interval

HTML code

```html
 <button class="mybutton">Button 1</button>
```

Javascript Code in a SCRIPT1.js file

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);

function ready() {
  let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".mybutton");
  buttons.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
      //do some stuff
      console.log("I was Clicked");
    });
  });
}
```

jQuery CODE  in a SCRIPT2.js file

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  //append the html  to add more buttons after some time
  setInterval(() => {
    $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: "/getButtons",
      async: true,
      success: function (data, status, xhr) {
        data.forEach((item) => {
          $("body").append(
            '<button class="mybutton">' + item + "</button>"
          );
        });
        const scriptsrc = document.createElement("script");
        scriptsrc.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        scriptsrc.setAttribute("src", "//script location here");

        $("head").append(scriptsrc);
      },
    });
  }, 10000);
});
```

The JavaScript attached to the buttons only fires up only once after the first Ajax request.The second time I get an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'buttons' has already been declared
```

Comment: It is just saying you redeclared "buttons" variable. Did you declare it somewhere else in your code?

Comment: You can change the first script, yes? Then it would probably make much more sense to use _event delegation_ in there, so that you _don’t have to_ run anything again after your AJAX request. (Plus, right now, if you ran that code again, you would be adding the cliock handler for all previously existing buttons a _second_ time, and that is likely not what you want to begin with.)

Comment: @MgThar  No.If i did ,I should have received the error the first time the ajax call was made.

Comment: @CBroe I have tried removing the script before adding it again  using ```document.querySelector('head').removeChild(document.querySelector('#myscript'))``` . .It gets removed well and re-added but still fails

Comment: Just because you remove a script _element_, doesn’t mean anything the _code_ contained in this element did when it was executed, also magically disappears. (Just because you burn a _letter_ you already read, does not mean your knowledge of its content also vanishes.)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the following script? To clarify if the 'let buttons' is issue or the ready() function is overriding the existing one.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init_fun);

function init_fun() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".mybutton").forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
      //do some stuff
      console.log("I was Clicked");
    });
  });
}
```

## Updated due to the comment.

In this case, if you are injecting the script1 after your ajax call, you will have multiple script tags which include multiple variables with the same name.

Instead of adding the whole script, call the function after the success callback of the ajax call. That should avoid multiple variable issues.

Comment: Still not working.I forgot to mention. I have not included the SCRIPT1.js  file in the html.I append it to the html after the ajax call.So i have not added the 'DOMContentLoaded' event because it does not work.Since the DOM Content will already have loaded.The script will not fire.

Comment: I call the appropriate function in SCRIPT1.js  into the JQUERY using Script(SCRIPT2.js) ?

Comment: yes. declare that ready function inside the script2 and just trigger that function on the jquery.

Comment: Also, if all you want to do is attaching an event listener on that newly created buttons, you can also declare the click function and attached them directly like ''<button class="mybutton" onclick="newfunction()">' + item + "</button>"'

Comment: Not working..not producing an error but the click function is not working

Comment: To attach the function directly will require me to add the script in html initially.Though i have some functions that trigger automatically in SCRIPT1.js file and they will trigger too which is not what i want as some html may not be ready

Comment: the functions won't trigger by themself. So, you can declare the function first and only trigger when they are supposed to do so.